# How to change font size and font weight dynamically in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I am trying to change the header part of my react app dynamically.
I want a different font size, font weight, title, and subtitle for the homepage and other pages of my react web app.
This is what I want on the homepage.
**Hello there** should be smaller on Homepage but **Welcome Back** should be large
[image]

This is what I want on other pages.
**Hello there** should be bigger on Homepage but **lorem ipsum lorem ipsum** should be small
[image]

This is my code for the homepage heading

```
const Hero = ({ fontSize, fontWeight, title, subTitle }) => {

return (
    <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
        <p className="font-heading text-lg font-normal text-white">Hello There ,</p>
        <p className="font-heading text-3xl font-bold text-white">{subTitle}</p>
         // another react component
    </div>
)
}

export default Hero
```

I want to know how to change this code dynamically so I can use it for other pages bypassing different props for font weight, font size, title, and subtitle.
I am using **react** and **tailwind css**

Anyone Please help me with this issue.
Thank You
**Edited:**

```
{pathName === '/' ? (
                <>
                    <p className="font-heading text-lg font-normal text-white">`Hello There ,</p>
                    <p className="font-heading text-3xl font-semibold text-white">{subTitle}</p>
    

        </>
        ) : (
            <>
                <p className="font-heading text-3xl font-semibold text-white">Hello There ,</p>
                <p className="font-heading text-lg font-normal text-white">subTitle</p>
            </>
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in-line styling

```
const Hero = ({ fontSize, fontWeight, title, subTitle }) => {

return (
    <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
        <p style={{fontSize:fontSize, fontWeight:fontWeight}} className="font-heading text-lg font-normal text-white">{title}</p>
        <p className="font-heading text-3xl font-bold text-white">{subTitle}</p>
    </div>
)
}

export default Hero
```

and do accordingly for the other element

Edit:
Or you can pass in fontSize and fontWeight as calss names

```
const Hero = ({ titleFontSize,subTitleFontSize, titleFontWeight, subTitleFontWeight, title, subTitle }) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
            <p className={`font-heading ${titleFontSize} ${titleFontWeight} text-white`}>{title}</p>
            <p className={`font-heading ${subTitleFontSize} ${subTitleFontWeight} text-white`}>{subTitle}</p>
        </div>
    )
    }
    
    export default Hero
```

Then whenever you use the component you pass those props e.g

```
<Hero titleFontSize="text-lg" subTitleFontSize="text-3xl" tileFontWeight="font-normal" subTitleFontWeight="font-bold" title="Title" subTitle="Sub Title" />
```

Or use if statement

```
const Hero = ({ scenario1, title, subTitle }) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
            <p className={`font-heading ${scenario1 ? "text-lg font-normal" : "text-3xl font-bold"} text-white`}>{title}</p>
            <p className={`font-heading ${scenario1 ? "text-3xl font-bold" : "text-lg font-normal"} text-white`}>{subTitle}</p>
        </div>
    )
    }
    
    export default Hero
```

and use it like this

```
<Hero title="Title" subTitle="Subtitle" scenario1/> // This will render Scenario 1
<Hero title="Title" subTitle="Subtitle"/> // This will render default -in your case its Scenario 2
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
I don't think we can use inline tailwind css

Comment: inline styles override any other styles, so it's safe to do them if you have a specifc fontSize and weight for this very instance

Comment: This makes sense to me

Comment: Is it ok to pass several props?

Comment: yeah its totally ok, but if you only have those two scenarios you can have and if statement there checking `if(secnario1) text-lg font-normal else text-3xl font-bold`

Comment: I don't understand if statement logic

Comment: If I use that then I have to write different conditions for title and subtitle according to route

Comment: @RishiPurwar I edited the answer, I showed the (if statement) solution there

Comment: Your solution is very good, but I think we only need one scenario if it's true(means we are on homepage) then do this other wise do this(means we are not on homepage)

Comment: I did like this
<Hero title="Title" subTitle="Sub title" homepage />
and then 
const Hero = ({ homepage, title, subTitle }) => {
<div className="mt-2 mb-8">
            <p className={`font-heading ${homepage ? "text-lg font-normal" : "text-3xl font-bold"} text-white`}>{title}</p>
            <p className={`font-heading ${homepage ? "text-3xl font-bold" : "text-lg font-normal"} text-white`}>{subTitle}</p>
</div>
    )
}

Comment: I got the correct result by the above code, but I am wondering should I have to give some value to the homepage prop?

Comment: since the value of type boolean then no need to give a value simply `homepage` will have a value of `true`

Answer (score 1):

I edit my answer

check this :

```
<p 
  className={"font-heading text-white " +
  (pathName !== '/'? "text-3xl font-semibold" : "text-lg font-normal")
} 
 >Hello There ,
</p>
<p 
  className={"font-heading text-white " +
  (pathName === '/'? "text-3xl font-semibold" : "text-lg font-normal")
}
>
     {subTitle}
</p>
```

Comment: If I do like this then I have to pass two font weight and two font size as props for title and subtile

Comment: @RishiPurwar tou right , I edited my answer

Comment: Nice approach... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**We can dynamic it by className**

```
 const Hero = ({ titleFontSize,subTitleFontSize, titleFontWeight, subTitleFontWeight, title, subTitle }) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
            <p className={`font-heading ${titleFontSize} ${titleFontWeight} text-white`}>{title}</p>
            <p className={`font-heading ${subTitleFontSize} ${subTitleFontWeight} text-white`}>{subTitle}</p>
        </div>
    )
    }
    
    export default Hero
```